# Best free crash reporter for iOS

Tags: ios, crash-reports, plcrashreporter, crashlytics

I want to get the crash logs of my app from the user, so that I can solve the show stoppers in my next update. For this purpose, I can use some third party crash reporter with my application code. Initially I start with [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). It is cool framework that will generate the logs (like apple created logs).

Then, I selected to implement [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) with my app. It creates the logs in a elegant way with more details than other crash reporters.

My questions are,

- What is the difference between these two? Which one is better in your experience?
- Is they are legal? Can I add them without any condition in my app?
- Or, is there any other free crash reporter available better than these two?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

We use Crashlytics in our commercial apps. Works great. Of course it's now owned by Twitter so assume some day it will be killed like everything they own. Nothing wrong with tracking crashes, in the long run it helps you create a better product. After all Apple supports crash reporting in iTunesConnect but it sucks big time.

Comment: Yes.. Asking customers to connect with iTunes and send back the log to us is a big process. That is the reason why I come to the conclusion to use crash reporters. My doubt is, if we integrate the crashlytics framework with our app, is our code is safe?